# MKMapView and pin locations

Tags: ios, location, mkmapview

Is it possible for someone to get the location of the pins from my app (lat&long). I have made an app that shows 158 pin locations. The app reads them from a JSON file that is in the main bundle. I have made quite an effort to combine this locations and I want to keep them private, but if it's something that someone can get easy I want to know and not get surprised.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone can access your Apps resources by using a app like iExplorer to browse the contents of your App bundle. One way to make it more difficult is to have a web service provide the location data to your app and then lock down the web service with API keys or something that checks if your App is requesting the data. You would of course need to use SSL so nobody could intercept your calls to the web service.